# ACCESS => SQL JOINS

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Is a `LEFT JOIN` in ACCESS the same as a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in SQL? What are the join equivalents in the two programs?

Answer (score 5):

They are identical.

The `OUTER` is not required.

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` is the same as `LEFT JOIN`

`RIGHT OUTER JOIN` is a `RIGHT JOIN`

`FULL OUTER JOIN` is a `FULL JOIN` - However MS Access cannot use `FULL JOIN`

`INNER JOIN` can also be written as `JOIN` - MS Access will not allow using just the word `JOIN`

Comment: How about an Inner Join in SQL?

Comment: @user1958651 an `INNER JOIN` is just an `INNER JOIN`, there is no `OUTER` for that but it can be used by saying `JOIN`